# package list - linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

when i was trying to fix an error in my linux mint, i accidentally, removed package list, now i can't install anything, how can i fix this?

i a beginner with linux..

i'm using linux mint 16 petra Mate edition.

follows the log:

```
charles@charles /etc/apt $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-tweak : Depends: python-compizconfig but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: sorry for the bad english.. :/

Answer (score 0):

How did you remove your package list? You should be able to restore it by finding the official repository list on the Linux Mint site, and then making sure your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list matches what they have.

Firstly, I would run sudo apt-get update though, in order to see what you're missing. That in itself might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: # add the tualatrix Personal Package Archive to your local apt repository list

Comment: # add the tualatrix Personal Package Archive to your local apt repository list. The tualatrix ppa is where the ubuntu-tweak are stored

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

# then update the  available list of installable packages.  so run "

sudo apt-get update"

# then run the apt-get install on the ubuntu-tweak package. then run

"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak"